# npm giving compatibility error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: npm

I have node version 4.2.6 installed in my machine. I have successfully installed npm as well but when I use `npm -v` it gives the following error

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${rel.min} to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/
```

Comment: Change the version then.

Comment: Maybe downgrade your Node.js.

Comment: How to install specific version of ubuntu?

Comment: try this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360567/error-npm-is-known-not-to-run-on-node-js-v4-2-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360567/error-npm-is-known-not-to-run-on-node-js-v4-2-6) perhaps this would work for you

Comment: My answer to the linked duplicate question installs the latest version of Node.js which has npm bundled with it. So npm works like a charm with Node.js because it has to, and npm can also be updated if necessary and it still works after it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, completely uninstall nodejs and npm.

```
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
```

afterwards type `npm -v` or `nodejs -v`, and if it returns something like `didn't find in folder /usr/bin/nodejs`

You will need to delete the old files of npm and nodejs. For example you could try

```
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs npm
```

After deleting try again `npm -v` or `nodejs -v`

If it returns `is not installed, to install type 'sudo apt-get install nodejs'`, then you can install nodejs and npm. This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04